# Fetching/dumping all information from a http post with perl

Tags: perl, http, cgi

hi i have a mobile client (a geofencing app), which will send triggered a HTTP Request (POST).  This will be fetched by a perl script on my web server.

At the moment i dont know how the structure of the HTTP Request. how i can fetch the full HTTP Request with perl to analyse it? Guess the best way is to dump the request to a file.

as far as i understand the CGI, for handling a HTTP POST Request i need to give the object names, but i dont know them. Is there a way to dump the full Request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CGI script doesn't receive the HTTP request. If you want to dump the form data received by a CGI script, you can use the following:

```
use CGI          qw( );
use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );

my $cgi = CGI->new();
my %form;
for my $param ($cgi->param()) {
   $form{$param} = [ $cgi->param($param) ];
}

print($cgi->header('text/plain'));

local $Data::Dumper::Indent   = 1;
local $Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;
local $Data::Dumper::Useqq    = 1;
print(Dumper(\%form));
```

Comment: thanks, ikegami this was bring me to the right way.... looks likle the request is a json the result from print(dumper($form)); is $VAR1 = [{"timestamp" => "Array(0x123),"id" => "Array(0x123)}].
with this i can work :)

Comment: Shouldn't look like that... ug, CGI's `Vars` does something very magical. Updated my answer.

Comment: You may also want to `print Dumper(\%ENV);` to see the environment variables set by the web server from the request.